# Storing constants in C++

Tags: c++, string, global-variables, constants

I want to store a directory structure of my program as a structure of constant strings but C++ doesn't let me do it in any intuitive way.

So this doesn't work:

```
struct DirStructure {
    static const std::string entities = "./entities";
    static const std::string scripts = "./scripts";
}
```

Neither does this:

```
struct DirStructure {
    static const std::string entities() const = { return "./entities"; }
    static const std::string scripts() const { return "./scripts"; }
}
```

(actually it does without const, but I don't quite like it).

This works:

```
namespace DirStructure {
    static const std::string entities = "./entities";
    static const std::string scripts = "./scripts";
}
```

but it has some other issues.

What is the standard way of dealing with such a problem (assuming I'd rather avoid `#define MY_SCRIPTS_DIR_PATH "./scripts"`)?

Comment: What are the "other issues" with the `namespace` version? It looks like the version that I would use. In each case, you should split the definitions and the declarations, so that the definitions are only placed in a single translation unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three approaches come to mind. First two resemble your approach, the latter is more typical of what I'd likely use

### #1 - anonymous namespace + inline `constexpr` functions

This solves all but 1 issue for my purposes:

```
#include <string>

namespace DirStructure {
    namespace {
        inline constexpr char const* const entities() { return "./entities"; }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string e = DirStructure::entities();
}
```

The one remaining issue would be that the string literal could not contain embedded NUL characters (which isn't a problem in the case of file paths).

### #2 - Aggregate initialization

Another approach might be

```
#include <string>

struct DirStructure
{
    std::string entities, scripts;
};

inline static const DirStructure& Config()
{
    static DirStructure _s = { "./entities", "./scripts" };
    return _s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string e = Config().entities;
}
```

### #3 - Expressive types

Usually what I actually ***use*** myself would be similar to:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::map<std::string, boost::filesystem::path> DirStructure = { 
        { "entities", "./entities" },  
        { "scripts", "./scripts" } 
    };
    auto const& e = DirStructure.at("entities");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first version should work fine, with a minor adjustment. You should split your declaration from your definition.

```
# Declaration in dirstructure.h
struct DirStructure {
    static const std::string entities;
    static const std::string scripts;
}

# Definition in dirstructure.cpp
const std::string DirStructure::entities("./entities");
const std::string DirStructure::scripts("./scripts");
```

Answer (score 1):

> source.cpp:4:54: error: in-class initialization of static data member
> 'const string DirStructure::entities' of non-literal type
>
> source.cpp:4:54: error: non-constant in-class initialization invalid
> for static member 'DirStructure::entities'
>
> source.cpp:4:54: error: (an
> out of class initialization is required)

`g++` tells you that an out-of-class initialization is required, so:

```
struct DirStructure {
    static const std::string entities;
    static const std::string scripts;
}

const std::string DirStructure::entities = "blah";
const std::string DirStructure::scripts = "blah2";
```

works. But I'd prefer the namespace one, too.